# AS3 XML Looping, grabbing attributes and children

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Here is my XML file:

```
<cm>
    <strategy_description>
        <category name="Account">
            <item name="tree">test1</item>
            <item name="type">test2</item>
        </category>
        <category name="Account2">
            <item name="tree">test1</item>
            <item name="type">test2</item>
        </category>
    </strategy_description>
</cm>
```

I want to output something like this:

```
Account
tree: test1
type: test2
Account2
tree: test1
type: test2
```

I got this far and manage to trace output all category and item nodes in XML format:

```
var categoryList:XMLList = xmlData.strategy_description.category;
for each(var category:XML in categoryList){
    trace(category);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need nested loops, for example:

```
var categoryList:XMLList = xmlData.strategy_description.category;

for each(var category:XML in categoryList)
{
    trace(category.@name);

    for each(var item:XML in category.item)
    {
        trace("  "+item.@name +": "+ item);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!